# Why input does reset cursor position in fn1 and do not in fn2?

Tags: vue.js

Why input does reset cursor position in fn1 and do not in fn2? I also tried `:type.prop` modifier.

I also checked that input is not recreated when `type` changed.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input :type="type" ref="input">
    <button @click="f1">1</button>
    <button @click="f2">2</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      type: "password"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    f1: function() {
      this.type = this.type === "text" ? "password" : "text";
      this.$refs.input.focus();
    },
    f2: function() {
      const t = this.$refs.input.type;
      this.$refs.input.type = t === "text" ? "password" : "text";
      this.$refs.input.focus();
    }
  },
};
</script>
```